# Systemverilog : how to extract match pattern into variable

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I can't figure out how to check whether a pattern defined by a regular expression exists in a string and, if so, save it as a variable.

```
Example : 
string name_reg;
string re_pattern;
string prefix_reg;

name_reg = "abcdef_ij_kl_mnop";
re_pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9])_.*"
```

I'd like to get prefix_reg = "abcdef".

I've used the code below to check whether the pattern exists or not, but I don't know how to extract the pattern found in a variable.

```
initial begin
    string input_string = "abcdef_ij_kl_mnop";
    string pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_";
    int result;

    result = uvm_pkg::uvm_re_match(pattern,input_string);

    if (result == 0) begin
      $display("match : %s");
    end else begin
      $display("not match");
    end
end
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Check your tool's user manual for built-in string methods for matching back references. Many tools have implemented SystemVerilog extensions that do this.